# How to check for every n value interval, but not exactly n

Tags: unity

Let's say I have a game where the player earns `n` number of points when they pick up an item; the value of `n` differs depending on what they picked up. When they pick up an item, a method gets called that adds `n` value to their current total score.

Pseudo code:

```
void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd) {
   PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
}
```

I want to give the player an extra life every time they reach `y` total points. Let's say `200`, for now.

Pseudo code:

```
void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd) {
   PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
   if (PlayerScore % 200 == 0) {
      GivePlayerExtraLife();
   } 
}
```

The problem with the modulus approach is that if `PlayerScore` is currently `190`, and we call `tallyScore(11)`, the modulus condition will fail, but I still want to give the player an extra life because they've passed 200 points. If we were to call `tallyScore(2)` again, I wouldn't want to give them an extra life that time becasue we already did when we called `tallyScore(11)` previously.

What's a good way to check that `PlayerScore` has passed an interval of 200 points?

To reiterate, as the game went on, and `PlayerScore` becomes `395`, I call `tallyScore(8)`, I would then want to give the player another extra life since they earned another `200` points.

Comment: One could also make a PlayerScore object with both responsibilities:  accumulate awarded points and count *down* to the next 1-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check pre and post status

```
void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd) {
   prec = PlayerScore / 200; //int division
   PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
   post = PlayerScore / 200; //int division
   if (post  > prec) {
      GivePlayerExtraLife();
   } 
}
```

Edit

If scoreToAdd > 200,

post - prec

gives the number of lives to add. If scoreToAdd can be less than O , post - prec works fine to eventualy subtract extra lives.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it doesn't rely on maintaining state between frames.

Comment: This has the potential to skip one-ups if the player has say 395 points and `scoreToAdd` is over 205. Depends on how important those 4 bytes are to you.

Comment: For the 205 like scenario, post  - prec gives you how many lives to add (and a negativ value if you manage negatives scores)

Comment: @dnkdrone.vs.drones Can you edit your answer to account for that edge-case?

Comment: @Philipp: That's a bit ironic, because I had suggested an edit to that end on this answer but it was declined for "changing the original intent". If the change finds its way into this answer after all, feel free to vote to delete [my answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112601/75714) for duplicating this one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of [dnk drone.vs.drones answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112549/75714) that will add more than one life if `scoreToAdd` causes `PlayerScore` to break more than one 200 point increment.

```
void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd) {
   lifesGained = PlayerScore / 200; //int division
   PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
   lifesToHaveGained = PlayerScore / 200; //int division
   while (lifesToHaveGained > lifesGained) {
      GivePlayerExtraLife();
      lifesGained++;
   } 
}
```

Comment: I am posting this variation because I had suggested it as an edit to said answer feeling that it captured the author's comment on his post, but apparently reviewers felt that it diverged too much from the original intent.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to track how many one-ups the player has earned.
This is assuming the players score can only go up.
Also assuming one-ups are gained every 200 points forever.

```
int oneUpsEarned = 0; //Somewhere.

void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd){
 PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
 if(PlayerScore > 200 * oneUpsEarned){
  GivePlayerExtraLife();
  oneUpsEarned++;
 }
}
```

If the player loses their 200 points when they get their one-up (like coins in Mario), you don't even have to track the number of one-ups earned.

```
void tallyScore(int scoreToAdd){
 PlayerScore += scoreToAdd;
 if(PlayerScore > 200){
  GivePlayerExtraLife();
  PlayerScore -= 200;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work. With your code, player earns 205 points, they get an extra life. Player earns 210 points, they would still get an extra life, but I don't want to give them another extra life until they've earned >= 400 points, and then again at >= 600, etc. Edit: Perhaps onesUpEarned should be initialized to 1, not 0, to make this work.

Comment: It should work. But you would need to initialize `oneUpsEarned` as 1. When the player earns 200 points, they earn a one-up. Now `oneUpsEarned == 2`, so they need oneUpsEarned * 200 points to get their next one-up, which is 400 points, and so-on

Comment: Yep, oneUpsEarned needs to be initialized to 1. Didn't see your comment when I made my comment edit.